# How to write explicitly the coefficients of the product of any two polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the polynomials $p(x) = p_{n}x^{n} + p_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + ... + p_{1}x + p_{0} = (p_{n}, p_{n - 1}, ..., p_{1}, p_{0})$ and $q(x) = q_{m}x^{m} + q_{m - 1}x^{m - 1} + ... + q_{1}x + q_{0} = (q_{m}, q_{m - 1}, ..., q_{1}, q_{0})$ I am asked to write to the product $p(x)q(x)$ using vector notation.

My problem with this problem is that this notation requires me to explicitly display the coefficients of the polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. Now, I know that these coefficients are given by the relation $\sum_{s+t=k} p_{s}q_{t}$, but, then, should I just write them that way and be done with it? That is to say:

$$p(x)q(x) = \bigg( \sum_{s+t=n+m}p_{s}q_{t}, \sum_{s+t=n+m-1}p_{s}q_{t}, ..., \sum_{s+t=k}p_{s}q_{t}, ..., \sum_{s+t=1}p_{s}q_{t}, \sum_{s+t=0}p_{s}q_{t} \bigg)$$$$= \bigg( p_{0}q_{n+m} + p_{1}q
_{n+m-1} +... + p_{i}q_{n+m-i} + ... + p_{n+m}q_{0},$$$$ p_{0}q_{n+m-1} + p_{1}q_{n+m-2} + ... + p_{i}q_{n+m- (i+1) } + ... + p_{n+m-1}q_{0},$$$$ \vdots$$$$ p_{0}q_{k} + p_{1}q_{k -1} + ... + p_{i}q_{k-i} + ... + p_{k}q_{0},$$$$ \vdots$$$$ p_{1}q_{0} + p_{0}q_{1},$$$$ p_{0}q_{0}\bigg )
$$

I really don't know if that's enough. For my taste I'm just directly applying the fact that $\sum_{s+t=k} p_{s}q_{t}$ in different ways. Is there anything else that can or should be done that I'm not taking into account?

I thank you in advance for your attention and answers, and I appreciate it sincerely.

Comment: What are you writing this for? It is enough if it does the job. One underlying idea here is (discrete) convolution.

Comment: This is not *vector notation*, is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution requires that the coefficients above $n$ and $m$ be zero, and that makes a lot of extra dummy terms.

A safe way to reason about these sums is by using the diagram below:

[image]

We consider the product of a polynomial of degree $15$ with one of degree $6$. If the degrees run from left to right and top to bottom, the blue diagonal shows the exponents combination for the term $x^5$. The number of terms are distributed as follows per exponent:

$$1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,5,4,3,2,1.$$

As you can see, there are three different "regimes" because the diagonals can joint left to top, bottom to top or bottom to right. (And if $n<m$, left to right instead of bottom to top).